# Elasticsearch ReadTimeoutError -

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hello i have the following Problem:

i have elasticsearch running on my server under 9200.

Im using - from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

i can successfully create an index, which i can see in Kibana and i also can verify that the index exists.

But i cant seem to insert a doc into the index which i created with the following code in python

es.index(index="index-1",id=1,body=[aJsonObject])

the only thing i get is:

---

### **Traceback (most recent call last):
File "elk-push.py", line 20, in 
res = es.index(index="index-1", id=1,body=doc1)
File "/home/de19520/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 153, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
File "/home/de19520/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py", line 403, in index
body=body,
File "/home/de19520/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 415, in perform_request
raise e
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))*

Here is my code im using:

````
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(
        ['localhost:9200'],
        http_auth=('uname', 'secret'),
        use_ssl=True,
        verify_certs=False,
        ssl_show_warn=False
)

doc1 = {
        "user":"tom",
        "age":"21",
        "height":"165"
}



res = es.index(index="index-1", id=1,body=doc1)
print(res)```
````

Comment: Add a timeout while creating Elasticsearch object (timeout=30)

Comment: Did already, didnt fixed my issue :/

Comment: check whether you've run out of memory